# NTFS Audit with Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs

So essentially I have the below script which generates output like follows for NTFS:

```
Folder Path   IdentityReference    AccessControlType     IsInherited        InheritanceFlags    PropagationFlags
E:\Folder\    DOMAIN\User1         Allow                 True/False         ContainerInherit     Object Inherit
E:\Folder\    DOMAIN\User2         Deny                  True/False         ContainerInherit     Object Inherit
```

Although this is useful, it would be even better if instead of just `Allow/Deny` I could get a output which indicates, `Read/Write/Modify/FullControl` flags.

See my below code, any ideas are appreciated!

```
$OutFile = "C:\Permissions.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "E:\Folder"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
    $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
    Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `$ACL.FileSystemRights`.

```
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited," +
          "InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags,FileSystemRights"

#...

$OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," +
           $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," +
           $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags + "," +
           $ACL.FileSystemRights
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who want it wrapped in a function try this:

```
Function Get-FolderPermissions {
 Param($FolderPath)

If(-not (Test-Path $FolderPath)){

    Write-Warning "$FolderPath not valid!"
    return

}

$FolderPath = $(Get-Item $FolderPath).fullname

$ACLs = Get-Acl $FolderPath | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }

$ACLs | Select-Object @{n='FolderPath';e={$FolderPath}}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType, IsInherited, InheritanceFlags, PropagationFlags, FileSystemRights


}
```

Then you can export to CSV like this:

```
Get-FolderPermissions 'C:\Folder' | Export-Csv 'C:\Results.csv' -NoTypeInfo
```

Or multiple folders from a parent folder:

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Folder' -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
$Folders | %{ Get-FolderPermissions $_.FullName } | Export-Csv 'C:\Results.csv' -NoTypeInfo
```